# (Java) Best way to display images?

Tags: java

I've been making a game for a while now, but its a bit slow and clunky. I was wondering if this had to do with the way I drew images on the screen. I stored individual sprites as BufferedImages and displayed them on a canvas, and redrew them when I needed to. My question is is there a better way to draw sprites? I feel as though having to redraw every BufferedImage when the player moves around is not efficient, and there has to be more clever ways of drawing graphics.

Comment: Generally speaking, the approach you're taking is correct, but without a runnable example its impossible to know if you're doing it right or not

Comment: Computers these days tend to have far more than enough power to redraw 2D screens completely every cycle, and that's what the vast majority of games do. Decades ago, they used to use tricks like erasing sprites and redraw them in order to not have to update the backgrounds, but such techniques have not regularly been used in a very long time. If your game is slow and clunky, it's probably for other reasons (unless you're trying to draw truly vast numbers of sprites).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had similar issues with run time speeds. What I did was reduce the number of times my program redrew to the screen. I used the Thread.sleep(int) method to accomplish this. By doing this it only drew to the screen a specified amount of times, rather than approximately 1000 times/sec.